# Extending a T type, delegating to T whatever behavior is need for its class

Tags: kotlin

I want to add some behavior to the T generic type of my class, but I still want my class to exist. I want a class to be both itself and the T type. For instance:

```
open class Foo(val bar: String)

class Bar(val baz: String) : Foo("bar") {

}
```

This is an easy case, because I know Foo type in advance. If I make Foo an interface, I can delegate it's methods to a parameter:

```
interface Foo {
    fun bar() = "bar"
}  

class Bar(val foo: Foo) : Foo by foo {

}
```

And `Bar` is still a `Foo`.

But what if I don't know what type it is at this time? I want Bar to be T aswell as Bar, and I thought of something like this:

```
class Bar<T>(val t: T) : T by t
```

But it doesn't compile. I wanted to use it in this fashion:

```
fun doWithFoo(s: String) {
    print(s)
}

fun unknownFoo() {
    val bar = Bar("baz")
    doWithFoo(bar)
}
```

This might be a bizarre use case, but it's necessary. I need it to capture arguments passed to a function, and make assertions over it, but I need the function to still be valid, so:

```
fun foo(b: Bar){
    print(b.toString())
}
```

If I want to create an argument capturer for the function `foo`, I could create something that captures it

```
class Capturer<T>(t: T) {
    //code that captures the value and make assertions over it
}
```

But then the function would become invalid:

```
val capturer = Capturer<Bar>(Bar("X"))
foo(capturer) //Invalid
```

So I need capturer to also be a Bar. This way the function `foo` is still valid.

How could I make the Bar class to be both a Bar and the generic type T?

Comment: Why would this be useful to you? What is your use case?

Comment: The use case is very specific. I'm doing it for a testing library, in which I capture values passed as arguments in a Matcher, for example an EqualityMatcher. But for the function to keep being valid, it must return the type it's capturing. I'll update the question to include this use case

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to make the class behave as it's generic supertype, but maybe there's an alternative I'm not seeing

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that I really got what you are trying to accomplish.

But maybe the following may help you solve your problem?

If you use

```
fun <T> foo(b: T) {
  //...
```

and

```
fun <T> doWithFoo(s: T) {
  //...
```

at least the call will not be invalid anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't exactly what I'm going for. I need a class to actually be T, and I think this isn't possible currently

Comment: hmm... do you know Mockito? They already implemented something similar, where you can call `when(yourObj.yourMethod(ArgumentMatcher.any() /* or the specific one!! */))`. Maybe that is what you are looking for? If so, here are the sources: https://github.com/mockito/mockito

Comment: It's something very similar I'm going for, it's actually to add it to [mockk](http://mockk.io)

Comment: I need the class to be T, because I want the possibility to have `eq(X)` and `!eq(X)`. This would be possible overloading the `not` operator, but only if I can create a class that's both T and itself

Comment: Currently, the only possible way is having `eq(X, inverse = true)` or `neq(X)`

Comment: but to be honest... what's the problem with `eq` vs `neq`? Which class would you want to adapt to accomplish that functionality? I am not sure whether it will work with the `mockk`-code as it is today. The `match`-method takes care to transform any matcher to the `T` (internally using recorder, etc.), so the `match`-method would need to be the one to get the negated matcher. The `.not()`-operator however would apply to the `T` which is not what you want, you rather want the `not()` to apply to the matcher. So: currently that will not work as you desire.

Comment: And to summarize, I think you are right. There is no such language feature to have class that is the `Matcher<T>` and at the same time `T`, but you may need to build something around to handle that (which in my opinion is not worth the feature ;-)).

Comment: I just played around with the Matcher a bit and the main problems are either that you are missing a `reified T` when using the `operator` and that you need to supply the method in `MockKMatcherScope` to be of most value, but there is already a `not(t : T)`. So the best is: either use `not(eq(` or `neq` ;-)

Comment: Indeed, for the time being, it's impossible. My goal was to actually implement a matcher that would have the `!eq` possibility. Thanks for the comments :)